# Inkscape Voronoi Diagram (Delunay Triangulation) Tutorial Causes Error Message

Tags: inkscape, how-to

Good Evening,

I am having the same problem to a Posting some Years ago. I have worked through previously suggested solutions carefully & dilligently. I believe my problem may be System Related;

[code]
System:
Kernel: 5.15.0-92-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.8.4
tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria
base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
[/code]

When I attempt to complete the exercise I get the following Error Message;

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/voronoi_diagram.py", line 31, in 
import inkex
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/**init**.py", line 11, in 
from .extensions import *
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/extensions.py", line 34, in 
from .elements import (
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/elements/**init**.py", line 10, in 
from ._base import ShapeElement, BaseElement
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/elements/_base.py", line 39, in 
from ..styles import Style, Classes
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/styles.py", line 34, in 
from .css import ConditionalRule
File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/css.py", line 27, in 
import cssselect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cssselect'

Whilst a very New Linux User it would seem to indicate Inkscape is unable to access possibly a Library of some kind? I am sure I am following the Tutorial correctly. I have converted the relevant Object in the Tutorial to paths.

Any Assistamnce Gratefully recieved,

RW

Comment: Hi.  We can't really help you solve tech problems like this here, especially problems that might be related to you OS or setup, or program errors. It's generally off-topic. If you think it's a bug you need to [report it](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/). I've tested the Extension on my system (Win 11), Inkscape 1.3, and it seems to be working. No errors.  Also you don't really need to convert objects to paths. It should work just fine with circle objects. Also what tutorial are you trying to follow? I could take a look and see if there's a problem.

Comment: Dear Billy, Thank You for Your kind response                                                                                     FYI the Tutorial is at;                                                                                                                                                                               https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hcxuwDKo6I&list=PLynG8gQD-n8BMplEVZVsoYlaRgqzG1qc4&index=3 I'll try my Linux Forums and see what I can discover. RW

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Appreciated your assistance, still getting to grips with Linux, Inkscape etc etc. Forums like this teach Us much even when We are not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem myself. The key is in the Error message thrown when I tried to use the extension in Inkscape;

"Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/voronoi_diagram.py", line 31, in import inkex File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/init.py", line 11, in from .extensions import * File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/extensions.py", line 34, in from .elements import ( File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/elements/init.py", line 10, in from ._base import ShapeElement, BaseElement File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/elements/_base.py", line 39, in from ..styles import Style, Classes File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/styles.py", line 34, in from .css import ConditionalRule File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/css.py", **line 27, in import cssselect ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cssselect'**

Inkscape (via Linux OS) calls upon a series of Libraries to effect the extension. I went to Synaptic Package Manager and checked installation of the various Packages called in the error message. As expected "cssselect" was not installed. After installation & reboot I successfully used the extension.

Being a relatively New Linux & Inkscape User I am still getting used to having to install addittional functionality. Thank You to all that responsed to my Post, I hope this helps someone like it helped Me.